# Add contact form on front page as block

Tags: 8, emails

I add contact form block in front page

[image]

And for some reason when I go to send messages it doesn't work. My site opens some page which is not front with this css, which doesn't exist on my front page. Also I don't receive any mail. On that page there is all content from front page but there is no css who is on front page.

```
<head-placeholder token="q2goFNv0--dtpJFM_4fZIJ8a13PQ4CARSwpHuSGhS5XqUhWfv60QQhZjM6B0JxHq-CohSC9hxg">
    <css-placeholder token="q2goFNv0--dtpJFM_4fZIJ8a13PQ4CARSwpHuSGhS5XqUhWfv60QQhZjM6B0JxHq-CohSC9hxg">
        <js-placeholder token="q2goFNv0--dtpJFM_4fZIJ8a13PQ4CARSwpHuSGhS5XqUhWfv60QQhZjM6B0JxHq-CohSC9hxg">
```

Also that page don't page  THEME HOOK: 'page'  suggestion. Its start from region.

And on **site.com/contact** Its work. I receive email, but after click on send messages I get this

> The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.

Comment: Add in settings.php
$config['system.logging']['error_level'] = 'verbose'; you will able to see the issue.

Comment: Did you look at the log entries? Anything relevant there? Or in the Status Report page?

Comment: +1 @ Stefanos Petrakis: "The website encountered an unexpected error" always means that there was an exception caught by the system. This is always logged in Reports/Log Messages. You should watch the reason first, and if you can't solve it, please update the your answer.

Comment: Thank you all, i fix this. Problem was in some module what I instal.. And that module was makem problems.. New is all good..:)